# Debugging MVC3 Source code with Ninject error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I am trying to understand how the Html Helpers are built inside MVC 3. So i downloaded MVC 3 source and added as another project in same solution to debug it.

I followed this steps.

1. Removed System.web.Mvc reference from my MVC Application
2. Added a System.web.Mvc Source code project reference for debugging.
3. In Web.config System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35 to System.Web.Mvc

However i have other `NInject`(`NInject`, `NInject.web.common`, `WebActivator`, `Microsoft.web.infrastructure`) references added in my `MVC` 3 application for dependency injection.

Now i am getting an error in `System.Web.MVC` Source saying ***'`An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MVCApp.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`*** in below `MVC` Source code of

```
public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) 
{
    try
    {
        return (IController)(_resolverThunk().GetService(controllerType)
            ?? Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                MvcResources.DefaultControllerFactory_ErrorCreatingController, controllerType),
                ex);
    }
}
```

> Checking **DependencyResolver.Current** property says
>   DependencyResolver.Current    The type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver' exists in both
>   'System.Web.Mvc.dll' and 'System.Web.Mvc.dll'

What more needs to be done in order to debug my MVC3App with MVC3 source code? how can i avoid this error?

Comment: @vtortola, I didnt find any for this. I dropped my plan to debug source code with NInject :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this solution: [Ninject + MVC3 is not injecting into controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343388/ninject-mvc3-is-not-injecting-into-controller/14354347#comment31644936_14354347)

Add this to the Web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    <!-- The following line was missing -->
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /> 
  </dependentAssembly>
```

It solved this problem:

> Checking DependencyResolver.Current property says
>   DependencyResolver.Current The type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver' exists in both
>   'System.Web.Mvc.dll' and 'System.Web.Mvc.dll'

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for giving a solution