# Still ninject in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

although there's a lot of questions round here about the same and I'm trying to follow this post that has been advised several times I can't make it work

http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/

I'm getting this error

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ProfileController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerActivatorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator.Create>b__0() at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerActivatorTracer.System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerDescriptorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateController>b__0() at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerDescriptorTracer.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'LoanBook.Api.Controllers.ProfileController' does not have a default constructor
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

I don't know if this post is still relevant or there's another way of make this work. I'm working with 2012 but using web api2 in 4.5. The Ninject.Web.WebApi package has just released unstable versions yet so I'm not sure if it's an option.

EDIT: By the way, the solution is not place in the same project as an MVC one. Maybe that's an issue

Thanks

EDIT: The controller looks like this

```
public class ProfileController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IPersonService _personService;

    public ProfileController(IPersonService personService)
    {
        _personService = personService;
    }

    //.. Methods

}
```

The error is in the NinjectDependencyResolver shown in the post I mentioned, in this bit

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
{
    if (resolver == null)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has been disposed");

    return resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
}
```

When it get to the return line

Comment: Ok, as per my answer, i still can't see the parameterless ctor. Try adding that

Comment: Yes if I add it, it doesn't raise the error but the _personService is null as is not injected

Comment: Best thing is to edit your post to show the ninject initialisation code as this could be where the issue lies. Also, post the line of code that is causing the failure

Comment: i edited my answer to show the expected ninject initialisation code that i'd expect to see. if you don't have this init code, then that is definitaly where the problem lies

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ninject binding with generic repository MVC returns error on Parameterless Constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723935/ninject-binding-with-generic-repository-mvc-returns-error-on-parameterless-const)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is telling you that you need to create a parameterless constructor in the controller, this could be due to ninject `RegisterServices()` not being setup correctly.

You need the following to sort the error:

```
public ProfileController () { }
```

I'm therefore assuming that you have the required ioc constructor along the lines of:

```
public ProfileController (IPersonService personService) 
{
    _personService = personService;
}
```

**[edit]** - so i'd expect your `NinjectWebCommon.cs` (located in `App_Start`) to contain the following for everything to work:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    /* other kernel.bind<>() setups */
    // assumes that your concrete class implementation
    // of IPersonService is called PersonService
    kernel.Bind<IPersonService>().To<PersonService>().InRequestScope();
}
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, but I think in this case the injection is not working right? I mean, for using the PersonService I would need to instantiate it in that parameterless constructor

Comment: See my edit, re the required 'pair' that you'd normally see. You'd then have your ninject initialisation to let the controller know which type of interface was to be converted to a concrete type

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand it's what I have in my controller so I shouldn't need the parameterless constructor. Thanks

Comment: Ye, i agree for your use, there is no requiremen, however, the error message is hinting at wanting that :-)

Comment: Problem is that then it uses the parameterless so for using the service I need to instantiate it in the parameterless constructor and I'm not taking advantage of injection

Comment: Hmmm... not sure i agree. IF, the ninject initialisation is set up correctly, then it should automatically set the required implementation up for you. If you are trying to instantiate a parameterless version in code and hope that it will inject, then this will not happen. The ioc only works via 'hidden' instantiation

Comment: Yes, I agree but the thing is that the error prompts me to use a parameterless constructor because it seems not to be able to use the one with the parameter. Therefore I would need to somehow populate the _personService in the controller and in the parameterless as you say no injection will occur so I will need to instantiate it

Comment: Tahnks @jimtollan, I had something similar. I was missing the InRequestScope() but even adding it stills fails, maybe is something I have to do with a controller factory?

Comment: mitomed, possibly the suggestion by trevor pilley could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723935/ninject-binding-with-generic-repository-mvc-returns-error-on-parameterless-const

Comment: Just a quick update. I couldn't make it work but following this it works fine http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/using-ninject-with-the-latest-asp-net-web-api-source/ To be fair I'm not sure if I was doing something wrong with the other solutions as I was trying to inject a dependency that I hadn't instantiation for and with the second solution I got the proper error that made me solve it