# Ninject.Web.Common and Ninject.Mvc isn't setting the DependencyResolver to use the NinjectDependencyResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

**UPDATE**

Starting a Bounty, I have added is a Visual Studio 2010 solution replicating the Ninject bug as this seems to be quite a localised issue.

[Ninject VS 2010 Solution](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101891564/NinjectTest.zip)

---

When I do the following:

1. Start Visual Studio 2010 (yes 2010 :-( )
2. File > New Project > Empty MVC 4 Application
3. Manage Packages > install package Ninject.Web.Common (which then installs Ninject and Ninject.Mvc)
4. Then do the following in a HomeController

Code:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public HomeController(IKernel kernel)
        {
            // Should have been injected
        }
    }
```

I get this:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

No parameterless constructor defined for this object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Stack Trace: 

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'NinjectTest.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +179
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +197
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

When I checked to see what the `DependencyResolver` was I saw this:

[image]

When I do the same with a VS 2013 Express instance and create a fresh MVC 4 empty web application I see that the `DependencyResolver` is the Ninject one.

I do have a runnable VS 2010 solution but all external file storage sites are blocked at my workplace so I will link it latter, if anyone has any thoughts in the meantime....

My solution in the meantime is to wire up the resolver manually but I shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Please don't make a print screen of your exception, but include the full exception details as text. This way it is easier to read and allows your question to be indexed by Google. This way others can benefit from your question.

Comment: good point I will update question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Ninject.Mvc3 package installed which is the one defining and setting the dependency resolver. I can see in the VS2010 solution you have uploaded that Ninject.Web.Mvc.dll is not referenced. Installing that package will also install Ninject and Ninject.Web.Common, but not the other way round.

Once you have installed and referenced that package (Ninject.Mvc3), you may get the same issue using it with MVC 4 as [here in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343388/ninject-mvc3-is-not-injecting-into-controller). Make sure the web.config is not missing a redirect for the System.Web.Mvc assembly, from version 3.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.0. The following line will redirect any version of System.Web.Mvc to version 4.0.0.0:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i didn't spot that I was missing the Ninject.Mvc3 package, I also tried adding the binding redirect but to no avail. Did those steps work for you?

Comment: I have tried with VS2010 and MVC 3 which is what I had installed at the office. That works nicely but obviously you are trying MVC 4. I saw people with that issue (another one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311479/asp-net-mvc-4-ninject-mvc-3-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-ob)) and also noticed that Ninject.Web.Mvc [has a reference](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/Ninject.Web.Mvc.csproj) to System.Web.Mvc 2.0.0.0. That reference needs to be redirected to version 4.0.0.0 in the case of MVC 4 so the issue made sense...

Comment: Just to double check, where have you added the assembly redirect? inside the `runtime/assemblyBinding` node of the main web.config?

Comment: Tried this again, I think I must have added the bindingredirect after I had started the solution, I've done a rebuild and is working fine now, thanks for spotting my mistake!! I will award you the bounty when SO will let me.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. MVC4 application, Ninject.MVC3. bindingRedirect exists in web.config. however still I am getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the resolver in the CreateKernel method.

```
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }
```

Create kernel method:

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));

        return kernel;
    }
```

To register your services:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ITheService>().To<TheService>();
        //add other services, etc
    }
```

You can get the Ninject dependency resolver from [this nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter.Unofficial/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for you reply, but I believe this is done in NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin which is in the Ninject.Mvc Nuget Package, see this link https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.cs#L55

Comment: That's correct, I'm using the unofficial version of the NinjectServiceLocator.